# How to programmatically access master database on Content deliver server in Sitecore?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

How to programmatically access Sitecore "master" database on a content delivery server? Where direct access to master database using the code.

```cs
  Sitecore.Data.Database master = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");
```

Is not possible.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. And what's more, you should not even try. This server is called `Content Delivery` server cause its only purpose is delivering the content. And Sitecore `master` database stores the content which is not published and should not be deliver to the end users yet.

I'm guessing (but it's only guessing), you want to store some user generated content in the `master` database and then maybe at some point publish it to the end users. If that's what you need, you should check all the articles about [Sitecore User Generated Content](https://www.google.com/search?q=sitecore%20user%20generated%20content).

I've seen in your other question that you're using `Sitecore Web API` for creating items in `master` database. You can also think about [Publishing items using Sitecore Web API](https://sitecorejunkie.com/2013/06/16/publish-items-with-the-sitecore-item-web-api-using-a-custom-resolveaction-itemwebapirequest-pipeline-processor/).

Comment: Ok than how will I publish the content If I cant access the master db ? For example in my case there is user generated content. How will I publish the content that the user entered in the website ?

Comment: Check the first link from my answer - it's a google search for "sitecore user generated content". There are plenty of different approaches all explained in details.

Answer (score 3):

A few months ago we had a quiet similar problem. We had the task to save UGC, in out case comments.

Our solution for the problem was to use Sitecore custom events. 
Basically we collect the data generated by the user, create a dedicated model and queue a event

```
CommentsRemoteSavingEvent eventmodel = new CommentsRemoteSavingEvent(commentModel); 

EventManager.QueueEvent(eventModel, true, false);
```

The first argument determines if the event is queued globally, the second one determines if it is queued locally. The Event Model is a custom class to store all necessarry information.

On the CM System we now only had to create a hook, which subscribe to theses custom events

```
public class CommentsRemoteSavingEventHook : IHook
{
    public void Initialize()
    {
        EventManager.Subscribe(new Action<CommentsRemoteSavingEvent>(CommentsRemoteSavingHandler.Run));
    }
}
```

This line of code subscribes to the CommentsRemoteSavingEvent, the eventtype fired on the CM System and lets a specific Handler run when the event is dequeued.

The Hook Itself can be added to the hooks via a simple config

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <hooks>
      <hook type="YOURNAMESPACE.CommentsRemoteSavingEventHook, YOURDLL" />
    </hooks>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>`enter code here`
```

The Handler itself could be implemented like this

```
    public class CommentsRemoteSavingHandler
{
    /// <summary>  
    /// This method is used handle the dequeued event  
    /// </summary>  
    /// <param name="e">The event</param>  
    public static void Run(CommentsRemoteSavingEvent e)
    {
        EventManager.RemoveQueuedEvents(new EventQueueQuery() { EventType = typeof(CommentsRemoteSavingEvent) });
          //// Use the CommentsRemoteSavingEvent which holds now all data
    }
```

The first line of code removes the event safely from the event queue, so it wont be dequeued again.

In the CommentsRemoteSavingEvent, which is given to you as parameter, are now all information you put in on the CD side, but now on the CM side.

So based on theses information you can simple create items and publish them as you want, because you are now directly on the CM System, like we did with our user generated comments.

I hope this can help you with the problem of transferring data from CD to CM and handle them on the CM system.

Answer (score 0):

I had same situation before, actually I did not use Sitecore Item Web APIs, because I want only three functions to perform the task, so I created my own  controller and i added my methods there which are talking to master database, and I exposed them from CM environment, and from CDs server I was accessing them using the CM URL :

```
example : http://cmsitecore/yourcontroller/yourmethod
```